# Use keyboard keys instead of mouse in calculator

Tags: javascript, html

Can somebody help me how to do this?      This    is my calculator and instead of using mouse     i want to use      the keyboard      function. how will i do that? below is the full code of my calculator.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
input[type=button] {
    color:white;
    border:0;
    display:block;
    height:110px;
    width: 90px;
 font-family: Broadway;
 font-size:200%;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 7px 11px 0;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
td{
 background-color:;
 
 

}
input[type=text] {
    color:black;
 font-size:300%;
     height:100px;
 border-radius: 5px;
  
 
}
#calculator {
 width: 425px;
 height: auto;
 
 margin: 100px auto;
 padding: 20px 20px 9px;
 
 background: #9dd2ea;
 background: linear-gradient(#9dd2ea, #8bceec);
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px #009de4, 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 
}

p{
 color:grey;
}

#clear{
 height:2px;
 width:2px;
 background-color: red;
}



</style>

<body background="background.jpg">


<div style="background-color: " id=calculator>

<center>
<h1>CASIO</h1>
<h3>Calas og Sinselyo</h31>
<br/>
</center>
<center>
<form Name="calc">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td colspan=4><input style="background-color:#F0FFFF" type="text" size=12 id="textboxes" Name="display"></td> //This is for the textbox of the calculator
  </tr>
 </table>
 <br>
 </center>
 <center>
 <table> 
  <tr>
  
   <td><input style="height:50px; background-color:#F08080" type=button value="C" OnClick="calc.display.value=''"></td>  //This one is for clearing anything on the textbox display of the calculator
  </tr>
  <tr> //below is the code for the numbers of the calculator
   <td><input type=button value="1" OnClick="calc.display.value+='1'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="2" OnClick="calc.display.value+='2'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="3" OnClick="calc.display.value+='3'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="+" OnClick="calc.display.value+='+'"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type=button value="4" OnClick="calc.display.value+='4'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="5" OnClick="calc.display.value+='5'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="6" OnClick="calc.display.value+='6'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="-" OnClick="calc.display.value+='-'"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type=button value="7" OnClick="calc.display.value+='7'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="8" OnClick="calc.display.value+='8'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="9" OnClick="calc.display.value+='9'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="x" OnClick="calc.display.value+='*'"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type=button value="0" OnClick="calc.display.value+='0'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="." OnClick="calc.display.value+='.'"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="=" id="equals" OnClick="calc.display.value=eval(calc.display.value)"></td>
   <td><input type=button value="/" OnClick="calc.display.value+='/'"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</center>
<p align="right">by: Raymart C. Lopez</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just add an event listener for keydown and get the key value pressed.

Comment: i dont know how to use that,never tried before

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Try and tell me what happens :)

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  var keycode = e.which || e.keyCode;
  var valueEntered = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
  console.log(valueEntered);
});
```

This will give you the value of the key pressed. You will want to do switch/if statements to determine which key was pressed. You can also check to make sure the value is a number with `isNan();`.

Comment: Snippet should be a complete working functional code. Not just "snippet" of one single JavaScript.

Comment: Looks good buddy... But: 1. This doesn't answer the question. 2. This doesn't work correctly. Pressing `=` gives `»`. Could you kindly check?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Goodness, I've had this problem before. I always forget about which event combinations to use. Please see my updated answer :)

Comment: the '=' button is working.. but others are not... but still good :)

Comment: @RaymartC.Lopez That's the main thing. EqualTo. Check my answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's working for me in chrome. Nice answer +1. I think he also wanted people to be able to enter numbers as well not just the `=`.

Comment: @RaymartC.Lopez Everything works man... If you click on the textbox and start typing `123+456=` see what you get.

Comment: @RaymartC.Lopez What browser are you using?

Comment: im using chrome also, everything is fine instead of the '+' button.

Comment: i noticed that when i press chracters such as ) ( * & ^ % $ #  @ ! then i press the '+' button it will work but if i didnt press any of that it will not work?.. why is that? confusing..

Comment: Are you using the numeric keypad or the standard number keys next to `backspace`?

Comment: ~!@#$%^&*()_+ backspace

Comment: @RaymartC.Lopez Thank you for your effort. I don't really understand what you are saying because I tried hitting all the keys on the keyboard and it seems to be working. Did I not understand what you said?

Comment: @www139 Thank you also for helping. maybe the problem is in my laptop i dont know why. thnks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need a event listener on the `input` for `=` alone.

```
$(function () {
  $("#textboxes, body").keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 187) {
      $("#equals").trigger("click");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

I have used jQuery. You can also use a jQuery-less version:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function (event) {
  if (event.which == 187) {
    $("#equals").trigger("click");
    return false;
  }
});
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/pegigulibe**

Comment: dont work.. can you give me the full code? combined with my calculator? if you may.. thanks... for my project at school.