# Accessing Values of Keydown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner creating a basic calculator app, expanding on a tutorial I followed. I'd like to add functionality to accept keyboard input in addition to the onClick events. I've tried the methods used in the docs, but it ends up duplicating the last clicked value instead of inputting the correct value. Here's my app:

```
import { useState } from "react"

function App() {

  const [calc, setCalc] = useState("")
  const [result, setResult] = useState("")
  
  const ops = ['/', '*', '+', '-', '.']

  const updateCalc = value => {
    if (
      (ops.includes(value) && calc === "") ||
      (ops.includes(value) && ops.includes(calc.slice(-1)))
    ) {
      setCalc(calc.slice(0,-1) + value)
      return;
    }

    setCalc(calc + value)

    if (!ops.includes(value)) {
      setResult(eval(calc + value).toString());
    }
  }

  const createDigits = () => {
    const digits = []

    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
       digits.push(
        <input type="button" 
        onClick={() => updateCalc(i.toString())} key={i}
        onKeyPress={() => updateCalc(i.toString())} 
        value={i} />
      )
    }
    return digits
  }

  const calculate = () => {
    setCalc(eval(calc).toString())
    setResult("")
  }

  const deleteLast = () => {
    if (calc === "") {
      return;
    }
    
    const value = calc.slice(0, -1);

    setCalc(value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="calculator">
        <div className="display">
          {result ? <span>({result})</span> : ""} 
          &nbsp;
          { calc || "0"}
          </div>

        <div className="operators">
          <input type="button" onClick={() => updateCalc("/")} value="/" />
          <input type="button" onClick={() => updateCalc("*")} value="*" />
          <input type="button" onClick={() => updateCalc("+")} value="+" />
          <input type="button" onClick={() => updateCalc("-")} value="-" />

          <input type="button" onClick={deleteLast} value="DEL" />
        </div>

        <div className="digits">
          { createDigits() }
          <input type="button" onClick={() => updateCalc("0")} value="0" />
          <input type="button" onClick={() => updateCalc(".")} value="." />

          <input type="button" onClick={calculate} value="=" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069792/use-keyboard-keys-instead-of-mouse-in-calculator does this solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the concept of useEffect and watch for the keydown event. If the key is pressed you can check the value and call `updateCalc` function in `handleKeyPress`:

```
// handle what happens on key press
  const handleKeyPress = useCallback((event) => {
    // Call updateCalc here
    console.log(`Key pressed: ${event.key}`);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // attach the event listener
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);

    // remove the event listener
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress]);
```

Comment: This is helping a lot. I'm seeing the keys on the screen, now to get it properly working with update calc.